# what the differences between tf.train.Saver().restore() and tf.saved_model.loader

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'd like to know the differences between `tf.train.Saver().restore()` and 
`tf.saved_model.loader()`.

As far as I know, `tf.train.Saver().restore()` restores the previously saved variables from the `checkpoint` file; and `tf.saved_model.loader()` loads the graph def from the `pb` file.

But I have no idea about when I should choose `restore()` or `loader()`?

Answer (score 0):

During training, restoring from checkpoints, etc, you want to use the saver. You only want to use the saved model if you're loading your exported model for inference.